# Difficulty display data as different column bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display 3 columns `1. Information
              2.HomeTeam vs AwayTeam
              3.Line`

I am able to display `Information` and `HomeTeam vs AwayTeam` column properly. But 3rd column `Line` is not being displayed as new column but its data is displayed in 2nd column.

Here is the code that I tried

x.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mlb-api',
  templateUrl: './mlb-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mlb-api.component.css']
})
export class MlbApiComponent  {
 loadedCharacter: {  
 homeTeamName:string, 
 awayTeamName:string, 
 line:string, 
 EventId:string,
 visitorTeam:string,
 homeTeam:string} = <{homeTeamName:string, awayTeamName:string, line:string, EventId:string, visitorTeam:string,homeTeam:string}>{};
    allhomeTeamName;
  allawayTeamName;
  allline;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }


ngOnInit() {

    let character = this.http.get('https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json')
    .pipe(map((re: any) => re.events));
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(([draftkingsResp, fantasylabsResp]) => {      

      //this.allNames = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.name);
      //console.log(this.allNames);

      this.allhomeTeamName = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.homeTeamName);
      //console.log(this.allhomeTeamName);

       this.allawayTeamName = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.awayTeamName);
      //console.log(this.allawayTeamName);

       this.alllabel = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.offers).flat().map(o => o.label);
      //console.log(this.alllabel);

      this.allline = draftkingsResp.map(r=>r.offers).flat().map(r => r.outcomes).flat().map(o => o.line);
       console.log(this.allline);
      //this.allline will have 'undefined' as well
      //if you want then you can filter
      this.allline = this.allline.filter(l => !!l);
      console.log(this.allline);
    });
  }}
```

x.component.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">




<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table summary="This table shows how to create responsive tables using Bootstrap's default functionality" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Information</th>
              <th>HomeTeam vs AwayTeam</th>
              <th>Line</th>


            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of allhomeTeamName">
                    <tr><td>{{n}}</td></tr>
                  </ng-container>


                </tbody>

                <tbody>
            <tr>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of allawayTeamName">
                    <tr><td>{{n}}</td></tr>
                  </ng-container>


                </tbody>



                </div>
              </div>

           <tbody>
            <tr>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of allline">
                    <tr><td>{{n}}</td></tr>
                  </ng-container>


                </tbody>


                </div>
              </div>
```

How can I display `Line` as separate column so that it does not merge with my second column?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of using *ngfor for columns.
You should create rows by ngfor.
In this way, rows are created based on an array of objects including your defined properties like Information, HomeTeam vs AwayTeam, Line and etc.
Your table body should be like this:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let score of Scores">
    <td>{{ score.Information }}</td>
    <td>{{ score.HomeTeam }} vs {{ score.AwayTeam }}</td>
    <td>{{ score.Line }}</td>
</tr>
```

I don't know what is these properties for but the table is created by an array of objects with view of binded values from each object of the array in each row.

Comment: Okay. Could you give an example or any refrence?

Comment: Okay. I tried your code `<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let score of allline">
    <td>{{ score }}</td>
    
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let score of allhomeTeamName">
    <td>{{ score }}</td>
    
</tr>
</tbody>`. Could you check?

Comment: Where can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to display table and iterate table rows `tr`

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
     <div class="table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Information</th>
                    <th>HomeTeam vs AwayTeam</th>
                    <th>Line</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let n of allhomeTeamName">
                       {{n}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </div>
</table>
```

TS (app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent {
  allhomeTeamName = ["Yellow", "Blue", "Green"];
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-jwxhwy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Hey it kind of works. But I want to display data as columns, not rows

Comment: @Karan Can you provide your code in stackblitz. Then I will be able to provide some input.

Comment: Here is the link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-rfcwko?file=src/app/app.component.html . I have updated my code